# Memory leaks on dynamically added Text View on Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have LinearLayout in which i dinamically add and remove TextView. To remove them i just call
.removeAllViews(); This off course causes a huge memory leak. Is their any way i release the memory or it's just an architectural design flaw on my side.

```
      public void myUpdateFunction() {

            //...

    ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.WordList)).removeAllViews();

    ArrayList<String> anagrams = model.getAnagrams();

    for (int i = 0; i < anagrams.size(); i++) {
        String word = anagrams.get(i);
        if (model.getFound(i)) {
            addWord(word);
        } else {
            addWord(word.length());
        }
    }

            //...
       }

public void addWord(String word) {
    ViewGroup list = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.WordList);
    TextView v = new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    v.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    v.setText(word);
    list.addView(v);

}
```

Comment: How does this cause a memory leak?

Comment: sorry, my bad, apparently .removeAllViews(); only schedules the memory to be released, and does not release it immediately. That's why i was i was seeing memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

Where is the memory leak? You don't need to release memory as you had to do in C/C++. The GC will collect your TextViews if there are no more references to them.

Answer (score 0):

don't try to add textview in viewgroup.
Make a design consisted of linearlayout, and add the textview, and delete view according to their index.